# Should I rely on SOURCE_ID when reading Android Contacts?

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-syncadapter

I am creating an android contacts app, so I regularly read user's contacts and store them in my app. To do this, I need to rely on some kind of `ID` so that I know which contact I should update (or add/delete) in my app  and [Contacts Provider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html) supplies several of them:

- `CONTACT_ID` is the aggregate contact id,
- each aggregate contact consists of one or more Raw Contacts, each with its own `RAW_CONTACT_ID`,
- and most important, each Raw Contact has a `SOURCE_ID`, which is supposed to be the server id, i.e. the id this contact has in this account's server.

I 've chosen to rely on `SOURCE_ID`, since this sounds like the most stable one. E.g. when user removes and re-adds the same account in their device, I wouldn't want this account's contacts to get different IDs, because I wouldn't be able to match them in my app.

**However**, only Gmail sync adapter seems to keep the promise documented below. Exchange sync adapters unfortunately do not, `SOURCE_ID` changes, and it's definitely not any server id, since it has a small number like `23:4`.

**Question**: Any ideas how to overcome this problem? Am I using the right `ID` for the intended use? Does exchange adapter stores the "permanent server id" in some other field?

**Documentation**: The `SOURCE_ID` [must be *unique* for each account type and should be *stable* across syncs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html#ContactsProviderMetadata):

> - Unique: Each raw contact for an account must have its own source id. If you don't enforce this, you'll cause problems in the contacts
>     application. Notice that two raw contacts for the same account type
>     may have the same source id. For example, the raw contact "Thomas
>     Higginson" for the account emily.dickinson@gmail.com is allowed to
>     have the same source id as the raw contact "Thomas Higginson" for the
>     account emilyd@gmail.com.
> - Stable: Source ids are a permanent part of the online service's data for the raw contact. For example, if the user clears Contacts Storage
>     from the Apps settings and re-syncs, the restored raw contacts should
>     have the same source ids as before. If you don't enforce this,
>     shortcuts will stop working.

Answer (score 1):

`LOOKUP_KEY` is what you're looking for.

> LOOKUP_KEY
>
> An opaque value that contains hints on how to find the
>   contact if its row id changed as a result of a sync or aggregation.

You should use a **pair** of `<CONTACT_ID, LOOKUP_KEY>` to keep track of contacts.
In normal use, use the `CONTACT_ID` value, but if your code gets a hint that the `CONTACT_ID` has changed (either missing, or unexpected contact name), you can use the `LOOKUP_KEY` to **find** the new contact-id.

Or you can use [Contacts.getLookupUri()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html#getLookupUri%28long,%20java.lang.String%29) to get a URI you can always use to quickly find a contact no matter what its CONTACT_ID or LOOKUP_KEY actual values are.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but what about the scenario of removing, re-adding an account? I guess `LOOKUP_KEY`s will change, no?

Comment: LOOKUP_KEY is not meant to be a stable ID, so, yes, it'll change, but you can **always** use Contacts.getLookupUri(id, key) to get a uri that will point to the same contact (no matter what its new id may be). the lookup-key contains `hints` to the system on how to find that contact

Comment: Unfortunately, `LOOKUP_KEY` doesn't do a lot of magic. It too depends on the `sourceId`. I did a test in which `sourceId` of `contactA` was `2:16` and `lookupKey = 1016i2%3A16` (notice that `2%3A16` is `2:16` url encoded). Then removed and re-added the account. `SourceId` of `contactA` is now `2:12`, `lookupKey = 1016i2%3A12`, and the worst part is that some random `contactB` has `lookupKey = 1016i2%3A16`. That's why when I call `Contacts.getLookupUri(id, key)` with `lookupKey = 1016i2%3A16` and use that Uri to retrieve the contact, what I get back is `contactB` instead of `contactA`.

Comment: What blows my mind is that when I tried to create a shortcut of `contactA`, from that point on, no `sourceId` ever changed, no matter how many times I removed and re-added the same account (exchange), even if I had removed the shortcut.

Comment: that's truly weird... by creating a shortcut you mean adding a shortcut icon to the homescreen that opens that contact's profile?

Comment: yes, there is an option in contact card *Add shortcut to home screen*

Answer (score 0):

First thing, it's not a good idea to store the Id in your application and hoping that the Id won't change over time and be consistent. You are right about '`SOURCE_ID`' column that it's more consistent compared to the other two (`CONTACT_ID` is the most brittle while '`RAW_CONTACT_ID`' persists at least until user logs out of an account and logs in again).

We had a syncable account with contacts and we used to keep the `unique id` in one of the general purpose columns in the '`raw_contacts`' table (SYNC1 - SYNC10). So although Google suggests that account providers use the database columns in a certain manner but it's upto the provider totally.

General rule to follow is, never use those id's for long term persistence and if you do so, expect them to change. Also since you are making a contact App, you obviously need some kind of reference key. In such case, don't go by the rule that all account providers will put their key in the same column. It's brittle but that's the way it is.

Edit  -  You should use ContactsColumns.LOOKUP_KEY (previous answer also cited the same). As per the Google Documentation -

> LOOKUP_KEY
>
> Added in API level 5 String LOOKUP_KEY An opaque value that contains
>   hints on how to find the contact if its row id changed as a result of
>   a sync or aggregation.
>
> Constant Value: "lookup"

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactsColumns.html#LOOKUP_KEY

You can fetch the lookup key if you have the contact Id using API's provided. Look here - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html

Comment: Ok, so you suggest that if I rely on `IDs` I should expect them to change over time. So what reference could I use that is more permanent, if not these IDs?

Comment: Your question has been answered by the other other answer. The key that you need to use is `Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY`. Generally the lookup key is a composite key which is generated out of many components. I just edited my answer